# Singular values of Kronecker product of random matrices

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, linear-algebra, random-matrices

I'm looking for a way to evaluate $\mathbb{E} \| (\mathbf{X} \mathbf{Q})^+ \|$ for a random matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n}$ and a (fixed) matrix $\mathbf{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times \ell}$ with orthogonal columns ($\mathbf{Q}^T \mathbf{Q}$ is the $\ell \times \ell$ identity matrix).
$ \| \cdot \| $ is the operator norm $+$ superscript denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse.

In my concrete case, the matrix $X$ is a Kronecker product of multiple (WLOG, 2) standard normal matrices $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{S}_1 \otimes \mathbf{S}_2$ where $S_i \in \mathbb{R}^{r_i \times n_i}$ for $i=1,2$ (here, $r=r_1 r_2 $ and $n=n_1 n_2$), are such that $[\mathbf{S}_i]_{jk} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$

Computing the distribution of $\sigma_{\min} (\mathbf{X})$ is possible since $\sigma_{\min} (\mathbf{X}) = \sigma_{\min} (\mathbf{S}_1) \sigma_{\min} (\mathbf{S}_2)$, and the values $\sigma_{\min} (\mathbf{S}_1),  \sigma_{\min} (\mathbf{S}_2)$ are independent and are given by Marchenko–Pastur law (MP).

Due to the Kronecker structure, there are entries of $\mathbf{X}$ that may not be independent of one another.
Moreover, the entries of $\mathbf{X} \mathbf{Q}$ are uncorrelated (at best) and not independent. Thus, it is impossible to use classical results such as MP that assume all entries are i.i.d.

Intuitively $\sigma_{\min} (\mathbf{X} \mathbf{Q}) < \sigma_{\min} (\mathbf{X} )  $ almost surely. The question is, of course, how small can the quantity $\sigma_{\min} (\mathbf{X} \mathbf{Q}) / \sigma_{\min} (\mathbf{X} )$ really get.

Would love to see ideas how to approach this.

---

### Some progress

---

Assuming that $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{Q}_1 \otimes \mathbf{Q}_2$ where $\mathbf{Q}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n_i \times \ell_i}$ such that $\ell_1 \ell_2 = \ell$ and $\mathbf{Q}^T_i \mathbf{Q}_i = \mathbf{I}$, then

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \| (\mathbf{X} \mathbf{Q})^+ \|_2 
&= \mathbb{E} \| ((\mathbf{S}_1 \otimes \mathbf{S}_2) (\mathbf{Q}_1 \otimes \mathbf{Q}_2))^+  \|_2 \\
&= \mathbb{E} \| (\mathbf{S}_1 \mathbf{Q}_1 \otimes \mathbf{S}_2 \mathbf{Q}_1)^+  \|_2 \\
&= \mathbb{E} \| (\mathbf{S}_1 \mathbf{Q}_1)^+ \otimes( \mathbf{S}_2 \mathbf{Q}_1)^+  \|_2 \\
&= \mathbb{E}  [\| (\mathbf{S}_1 \mathbf{Q}_1)^+ \|_2 \| \mathbf{S}_2 \mathbf{Q}_1)^+  \|_2] \\
&= \mathbb{E}  [\| (\mathbf{S}_1 \mathbf{Q}_1)^+ \|_2 \mathbb{E} \| \mathbf{S}_2 \mathbf{Q}_1)^+  \|_2] 
\end{align}
$$

where we know that $ \mathbb{E}  \| (\mathbf{S}_i \mathbf{Q}_i)^+ \|_2 \leq \frac{e \sqrt{n_i}}{n_i - \ell_i} \leq \frac{e \sqrt{n_i}}{n_i - \ell} $ (explained for example in [this](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/090771806) paper).
And we conclude that in this case, we have a bound: $\mathbb{E} \| (\mathbf{X} \mathbf{Q})^+ \|_2 \leq \frac{e^2 \sqrt{n}}{(n_1 - \ell)(n_2 - \ell)}  $.

Note that the above bound holds not just for $\ell_1,\ell_2$ such that $\ell_1 \ell_2 = \ell$ but for any $2 \leq \ell_1,\ell_2 \leq \ell$. So we can take $\ell_1 = \ell_2 = \ell$.

If $\mathbf{Q} $ is not a Kronecker product of two partial isometry matrices, the above bound still hold if  $ \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{Q}^T = \mathbf{U}  \bar{\mathbf{Q}} \bar{\mathbf{Q}}^T  \mathbf{U}^T $ where $\bar{\mathbf{Q}} = \bar{\mathbf{Q}}_1 \otimes \bar{\mathbf{Q}}_2$ for a unitary matrix $\mathbf{U} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 n_2 \times n_1 n_2}$.

This leads to the following question: when is an orthogonal projection $\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{Q}^T$ unitarily similar to another orthogonal projection $\bar{\mathbf{Q}} \bar{\mathbf{Q}}^T$ where $\bar{\mathbf{Q}}$ has a kronecker product structure?

#### Update 2:

I conducted some numerical experiments, and it seems that it is always possible to find $\bar{\mathbf{Q}}_1 , \bar{\mathbf{Q}}_2$ such that $\bar{\mathbf{Q}} \bar{\mathbf{Q}}^T {\mathbf{Q}} {\mathbf{Q}}^T = {\mathbf{Q}} {\mathbf{Q}}^T \bar{\mathbf{Q}} \bar{\mathbf{Q}}^T $ where $\bar{\mathbf{Q}}_1 ,\bar{\mathbf{Q}}_2$ have orthogonal columns and $\bar{\mathbf{Q}} = \bar{\mathbf{Q}}_1 \otimes \bar{\mathbf{Q}}_2$

So this claim seems like something that might be real and provable.

Comment: Notice the typographical difference between $||a|| ||b||,$ coded as `||a|| ||b||`, and $\|a\|\|b\|,$ coded as `\|a\|\|b\|`. That is why I edited this in the way that I did.